# Remove extra TK dialog box and combining boxes

Tags: python, tkinter, dialog, user-input

Writing code that pulls lyrics given an artist name and song by taking a user input of each variable. It then pulls it from a website and displays the lyrics in a new dialog box. When I run this code, I get an extra box titled "tk". Also, I would like to know how to combine the first to dialog boxes that take the user's input of the artist and song.

```
from tkinter.simpledialog import SimpleDialog

import requests

import json

from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
import json
from tkinter import Tk, Button, Frame, Entry, END
from tkinter import *

from tkinter import simpledialog

application_window = tk.Tk()


artist = simpledialog.askstring("Artist", "What is the artist name?",
                                parent=application_window)

song = simpledialog.askstring("Song", "What is the song name?",
                                parent=application_window)

url = "https://api.lyrics.ovh/v1/" + artist + "/" + song

response = requests.get(url)
try:

    json_data = json.loads(response.content)
    lyrics = json_data["lyrics"]

except KeyError:
    print("")

class ABC(Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.make_widgets()

    def make_widgets(self):

        self.winfo_toplevel().title(artist.capitalize() + "-" + song.capitalize())

        label = Entry(self)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x")

try:
    root = Tk()
    abc = ABC(root)
    text = Text(root)
    text.insert(INSERT, lyrics)
    text.pack()

    root.mainloop()
except NameError:
    print("Invalid artist or song title")
```

Comment: `tk` is main window - like in any other program. And like in any other program `simpledialog` are only for display extra informations which you don't wnat to display in main window. If you want to combine inputs in one dialog then you should use main window with widget Entry, Label, Button to build own window. Standard dialogs can't be combined in one window.

Comment: BTW: you can use `json_data = response.json()`

Comment: BTW: `Tk()` is used to create main window in program, `Toplevel()`  is use for second, third window - like own dialogs, message box, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tk` is main window which is created automatically (if you don't create it manually) and you should use it to display your result or to ask for artist, song and later to display lyrics.

You can't combine standard dialogs - you have to create own dialog using main window `Tk` or `Toplevel` window (which is used to create second and next window - like dialog windows)

This is my version. I tried to create simple example but finally I made something more complex but code inside classes seems cleaner and more readable.

Program at start create `MainWindow` (`Tk`) with `Text` for lyrics and it automatically opens `DialogWindow` (`Toplevel`) to ask for artist and song. After closing dialog it gets lyrics and puts in `Text` in `MainWindow`.

There is button to open dialog again to search new artist and song.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.messagebox as msg
import requests

class DialogWindow(tk.Toplevel):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwars):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwars)
        self.title('My Dialog')

        self.artist = ''
        self.song = ''

        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        label = tk.Label(self, text="What is the artist name?")
        label.pack()

        self.entry_artist = tk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_artist.pack()

        label = tk.Label(self, text="What is the song name?")
        label.pack()

        self.entry_song = tk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_song.pack()

        button = tk.Button(self, text='OK', command=self.on_click)
        button.pack()

    def on_click(self):
        # get values from Entries because `destroy` (which will close window)
        # will remove widgets from memory and there will be no access to Entries

        self.artist = self.entry_artist.get()
        self.song = self.entry_song.get()

        self.destroy()


class MainWindow(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.title('My Result')

        self.artist = ''
        self.song = ''
        self.lyrics = ''

        self.create_widgets()

        # open dialog 1 second after start
        self.after(1000, self.on_click)

        self.mainloop()

    def create_widgets(self):

        self.text = tk.Text(self)
        self.text.pack()

        button = tk.Button(self, text='Open Dialog', command=self.on_click)
        button.pack()

    def on_click(self):
        dialog = DialogWindow(self)
        self.wait_window(dialog) # wait for dialog close

        self.artist = dialog.artist
        self.song = dialog.song

        self.get_data()

    def set_title(self):
        self.title(self.artist.capitalize() + "-" + self.song.capitalize())

    def get_data(self):
        url = "https://api.lyrics.ovh/v1/{}/{}".format(self.artist, self.song)
        try:         
            response = requests.get(url)
            data = response.json()
        except Exception as ex:
            print('Exception:', ex)
            msg.showerror('Exception', ex)
            data = dict()

        if 'error' in data:
            print('Error:', data['error'])
            msg.showerror('Error', data['error'])
        else:
            if 'lyrics' in data:
                self.lyrics = data['lyrics']

                self.text.delete('1.0', 'end')
                self.text.insert('end', self.lyrics)

                self.set_title()
            else:
                msg.showerror('Error', "No Lyrics")



if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainWindow()
```

---

[image]